# How to add running ID in a single UPDATE statement (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, sql-update

let's assume I have a table tab1 in my **Oracle DB 12.1**, which has a column record_id (type NUMBER) and many other columns, among them a column named exchg_id.

This record_id is always empty when a batch of new rows gets inserted into the table. What I need to do is to populate the record_id with values 1..N for all rows that satisfy a condition `...WHERE EXCHG_ID = 'something'` and number of such rows is N. Of course I know how to do this procedurally (in a for-loop), but I'd like to know if there's an faster way using a single UPDATE statement. I imagine something like this:

```
UPDATE tab1 SET record_id = {1..N} WHERE exchg_id = 'something';
```

Many thanks for your help!

**UPDATE:** the order of the rows is not important, I need no specific ordering. I just need unique record_id's 1..N for any given exchg_id.

Comment: you want to just update the rows with sequential value 1.2.3.4. in any order (of the rows) for a given exchg_id?

Comment: yes, I don't care about the order of the rows. Sorry for not pointing it out in the original text

Comment: Assuming you only want to add this "record_id" to new rows, how do you distinguish them from rows that were in the table already (and that may also satisfy whatever condition you have)? Or does the condition do that already, perhaps a condition like "added_date > (something)"?

Comment: That's not a problem. I know (from a different table) the value of exchg_id that these new rows must have. No other rows will satisfy the where condition. I can possibly have two new batches at the same time (rows from both of them with record_id = null), but these will have different exchg_id's. So I will process the batches one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`rownum`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/pseudocolumns008.htm) to set record_id to 1 to N :

```
UPDATE tab1 SET record_id = rownum WHERE exchg_id = 'something';
```

If you have some offset, say 10, then use `rownum + 10`

Comment: Probably need to add `and record_id is null` to the `where` clause.

Comment: @mathguy - Probably. Depends on what OP needs.

Comment: No, actually I was wrong - I missed the part where the OP says "this record_id is always empty when a batch of new rows gets inserted..." So that part is OK. I asked the OP another question - about distinguishing "new" rows from "old", assuming some of the "old" rows may also satisfy the condition he/she has in mind. Since "in the past" the conditions may not have been satisfied by some rows, those "old" rows may still have null in `record_id` so just checking for that will not suffice.

Comment: It works! I thought my eyes deceive me! :) I know about the rownum column, but I expected that it is computed at some other stage of query processing, which (in a typical Oracle fashion) would prohibit such use. Fortunately I was wrong.